# How can I save the return value of a javascript function in a django template variable?

Tags: javascript, django, onclick

Can anybody help me?

I'm doing comments features in django and I stopped because I don't know how to do this.

My idea is to set a variable value with `comment.id` for each comment when clicking on the "RESPONDER" button and save it to a django template variable to access it after posting an answer.

The form is displayed when you click on the button, showing the CSS class and the anchor link.

post.html:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  <input class="blog__answer__reply" type="button" name="comment_parent_id" onclick="comment_parent_id=set_comment_parent_id({{ comment.id|escapejs }})" value="RESPONDER">
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def add_comment(request, post_slug):
  try:
    comment_parent_id = int(request.POST.get('comment_parent_id'))
  except:
    comment_parent_id = None
```

functions.js:

```
function set_comment_parent_id(comment_id) {
  return comment_id
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

post.html:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  <input class="blog__answer__reply" type="button" name="comment_parent_id" onclick="comment_parent_id=set_comment_parent_id({{ comment.id|escapejs }})" value="RESPONDER">
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def add_comment(request, post_slug):
  try:
    comment_parent_id = int(request.POST.get('comment_parent_id'))
  except:
    comment_parent_id = None
```

functions.js:

```
function set_comment_parent_id(comment_id) {
  return comment_id
}
```